# inherited class passing in @RequestMapping with MockMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have class `Type1` like this:

```
public class Type1 extends TypeParent {}
```

I have a method post in my controller witch I'll test with `MockMvc` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/actions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Name> gettypes(@Valid @RequestBody Type1 request) { ... }
```

But I don't understand why the following test code doesn't work.

```
Type1 type= new Type1();

mockMvc.perform(post("/actions").contentType(JsonUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(JsonUtils.toJson(type)))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(print());
```

Output:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>

Otherwise with : `TypeParent typeParent = new TypeParent();` it's work very fine:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/actions").contentType(JsonUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
    .content(JsonUtils.toJson(typeParent)))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(print());
```

I understood that to passing an inherited object doesn't work, how can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please try this: `mockMvc.perform(post("/actions").contentType(JsonUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(JsonUtils.toJson(type)))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());`
and put the error output here?

Comment: Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 400

Comment: I think the problem in ( @RequestBody Type1 request) because 'type' is inherited another class , it should be work. but I don't know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem... it's weird :

In the class Type1 I have a function :  isEmpty(){..}

When I convert it to json I get this:
{
  "empty":true,
}

The solution that I change name of this function to myFctEmpty(){..} !!!!